# general solution to fractional differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fractional-calculus

I'd like to know the existence of the general solution to the following fractional differential equation $$D_{0+}^{\alpha} y(t)=0  \text{,}\label{1} \tag{1}$$
where $\alpha \in (1,2)$ and
$$  D_{0+}^{\alpha} y(t)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right)^2 \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds  \text{.}  $$

I know that $t^{\alpha-1}$ and $t^{\alpha-2}$ are solutions to problem \eqref{1}.

**My question** is whether $C_1t^{\alpha-1} + C_2 t^{\alpha-2}$ is the general solution to problem \eqref{1}.

Note that $D_{0+}^{\alpha}$ has second order derivative.

**My attempt**:
Let $Y(t)=\int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}}$ for fixed $y$. Then
$y$ is a solution to problem \eqref{1} if and only if $Y$ is a solution to problem $Y''(t)=0$.

We also know that

1. $D_1+D_2 t$ : a general solution to problem $Y''(t)=0$.
2. $y(t)=t^{\alpha-1} \implies Y(t)=Ct$ and  $y(t)=t^{\alpha-2} \implies Y(t)=C$ for a constant $C=\int_0^1 (1-v)^{1-\alpha}dv. $

I think I can prove it using them, but I'm not sure.

I would be grateful if you could give any comment for my question.

Comment: Does $D$ contain the square of derivative, or this expression means something other?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov The definition of $D_{0+}^{\alpha}$ was given below $(1)$.

Comment: Detalize it, please. What is the sense of the differential operator square?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov  Actually, I don’t understand what you want to know. But, the following link might be helpful. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: Therefore, the square in the definition should be eliminated.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov  I don’t think so. Note that $\alpha \in (1,2).$

Comment: Maybe you can fractionally integrate both sides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $y: \mathbf R^+\rightarrow \mathbf R$ is such that $\int_0^\infty |f(t)e^{-at}|dt<\infty$ for some $a\ge0$. You can apply [the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) $\mathcal L$ on $Y$ which is defined by OP in his question since
$$Y(t) = y*t^{1-\alpha}$$
where $*$ stands for the convolution operator, and $Y$ is a power function thus converges under the Laplace transform. We will repeatedly use the property that
$$\mathcal L\{t^q\}(s)=\frac{\Gamma(q+1)}{s^{q+1}},\quad \forall t>0,\,\text{Re}(s)>0,\, \text{Re}(q)>-1.$$
and the transformation is invertible. Apply the Laplace transform on $Y=D_1+D_2t$.
$$\mathcal L\{Y\} = \mathcal L\{y\}\mathcal L\{t^{1-\alpha}\}=\mathcal L\{y\}\frac{\Gamma(2-\alpha)}{s^{2-\alpha}}=\frac{D_1}{s}+\frac{D_2}{s^2},$$
then
$$\mathcal L\{y\}(s)=\frac{a_1}{s^{\alpha-1}}+\frac{a_2}{s^\alpha}.$$
Take the inverse Laplace transform
$$y(t)=b_1t^{\alpha-2}+b_2t^{\alpha-1}.$$
$a$'s and $b$'s above are constants.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question.  $t^{1-\alpha} is singular at $t=0,$ since $\alpha \in (1,2).$ I wonder if it is all right.

Comment: @04170706: $\frac1{t^{\alpha-1}}dt=\frac1{2-\alpha} dt^{2-\alpha}$ for $\alpha<2$. So $\frac1{t^{\alpha-1}}$ integrable around $t=0^+$. For a fixed $t$, so long as $f$ is not singular at $t^-$, it will be fine. But the equation for $Y$ is at most linear for all $t>0$, $f$ cannot be singular at any $t>0$. I can add these details into my answer later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{green}{\textbf{Version of 30.10.21.}}$

Starting from the Riemann-Liouville fractional integral in the form of
$$\text D_{0+}^{-\beta} f(t)=\dfrac1{\Gamma(\beta)} \int\limits_0^t (t-x)^{\beta-1} f(x)\,\text dx,\quad\text{where}\quad \text D=\dfrac{\text d}{\text dt},\quad \beta\in(0,1)\tag1$$
(see the link from the OP comments), and assuming $\,\beta=2-\alpha,\,$ one can get
$$\text D_{0+}^{\alpha-2}y(t)=\dfrac1{\Gamma(2-\alpha)}\int\limits_0^t (t-x)^{1-\alpha}y(x)\,\text dx, \quad\text{where}\quad \alpha\in(1,2),\tag2$$
wherein
$$\text D_{0+}^{\alpha-2}t^{\omega}
=\dfrac1{\Gamma(2-\alpha)}\int\limits_0^t x^{\omega}(t-x)^{1-\alpha}\,\text dx
=\dfrac{t^{\omega-\alpha+2}}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)}
\int\limits_0^t \left(\dfrac xt\right)^{1-\alpha}\left(1-\left(\dfrac xt\right)\right)^{\omega}\,\text d\left(\dfrac xt\right),$$
$$\text D_{0+}^{\alpha-2}t^{\omega}
=\dfrac{\operatorname B(2-\alpha,\omega+1)} {\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \,t^{\omega-\alpha+2}
=\dfrac{\Gamma(\omega+1)} {\Gamma(\omega-\alpha+3)} \,t^{\omega-\alpha+2},\tag3$$
$$\text D_{0+}^{\alpha-1}t^{\omega}
=\begin{cases}
0,\quad\text{if}\quad \omega=\alpha-2\\[4pt]
\dfrac{\Gamma(\omega+1)}{\Gamma(\omega-\alpha+2)} \,t^{\omega-\alpha+1}, \quad\text{otherwize},
\end{cases}\tag4$$
$$\text D_{0+}^{\alpha}t^{\omega}
=\begin{cases}
0,\quad\text{if}\quad \omega\in\{\alpha-2,\alpha-1\}\\[4pt]
\dfrac{\Gamma(\omega+1)}{\Gamma(\omega-\alpha+1)} \,t^{\omega-\alpha},
\quad\text{otherwize}.
\end{cases}\tag5$$
Used approach and formulas $(3)-(5)$ allow to solve certain linear ODEs, which contain fractional derivatives.

In particular, the given ODE has the common solution in the form of
$$y(t)=C_1e^{(\alpha-1)t}+C_2e^{(\alpha-2)t}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, your definition was wrong. See, in the link I posted, Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative with $\alpha \in (1,2)$ and $n=2$. The square derivative is used in the definition of fractional derivative. I am sorry for that I didn’t use the same format and I made you misunderstand the definition of fractional derivative.

Comment: Also you duplicated the method of the Laplace transform from my answer which was posted 2 hours before yours were without acknowledging it.

Comment: @Hans 1) Cauchy was the first; 2) our answers are different, and my one is detalized; 3) the time difference is significantly less.

Comment: @04170706 Thank you for the comments! Renewed..

Comment: What are the "certain linear ODEs"? Why does this imagined and hidden ODE give those solutions? The OP has already stated they are sufficient solutions. His question is whether these are necessarily the only solutions. You are merely repeating what is already known and not answering his question. This is no answer or proof whatsoever.

Comment: @Hans Your critic looks as flame.

Comment: It is not flaming. Every statement of mine is correct. If you do not think so, which part of my comment do you consider false? Also why did you erase my earlier comment?

Comment: @Hans I've only flagged it - my first case at the 6 years.

Comment: Flagged it as what? Was my deleted comment not true for the first version of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Only integration, differentiation, and algebra answer:

Note that you use an unfamiliar definition of the fractional derivative. Let me try using the inverse of the fractional derivative called which can be represented via [Fractional Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalIntegral.html) and [Cauchy’s formula for repeated integration](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration):

Your equation is simply:

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right)^2 \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds=0 $$

Let’s integrate twice wrt $t$ and ignore all other constants:

$$\iint\frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right)^2 \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds (dt)^2=\iint\frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right)^2 \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds (dt)^2=\iint 0(dt)^2\implies \int\frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \left( \frac{d}{dt} \right)\int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds+c_0 dt=\int 0+c_1dt\implies \frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds+c_0t+c_3 = c_1t+c_2$$

Therefore we can combine constants:

$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds= c_1t+c_2$$

According to the [Riemann–Liouville fractional integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) section on Wikipedia, the nth integral is defined by:

$$\,_0D^{-\alpha}_t f(t) =\frac1{\Gamma(a)} \int_0^t(t-x)^{\alpha-1}f(x)dx$$

Therefore:

$$\,_0D^{-\alpha}_t  \frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds=\,_0D^{-\alpha}_t(c_0t+c_1)\implies \frac1{\Gamma(a)} \int_0^t(t-s)^{\alpha-1}\frac{1}{\Gamma(2-\alpha)} \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, dsds=\frac1{\Gamma(2-\alpha)\Gamma(a)} \int_0^t\int_0^t y(s) dsds=\frac1{\Gamma(a)} \int_0^t(t-s)^{\alpha-1}(c_0 s+c_1)ds$$

You can also just notice that the fractional derivative is just repeated differentiation, so we can just integrate both sides repeatedly and include the $\alpha$ as a constant:

$$ \int_0^t \frac{y(s)}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, ds= c_1t+c_2\implies \int_0^t  \int_0^t \frac{y(s)(t-s)^{\alpha-1}}{(t-s)^{\alpha-1}} \, dsds=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^t(c_0s+c_1)(t-s)^{\alpha-1}ds$$

Therefore:
$$\left(\int_0^t\right)^2y(s)(dt)^2=\int_0^t(c_0s+c_1)(t-s)^{\alpha-1}ds$$

If you take it like a repeated integral, you would get a solution as:$$y=c_0t^{\alpha-1}+c_1 t^\alpha=D^{-\alpha}_t (c_0 t+c_1)$$

Here is the actual solution after evaluation of the integral and differentiating twice:

$$\left(\int_0^t\right)^2y(s)(dt)^2=\int_0^t(c_0s+c_1)(t-s)^{\alpha-1}ds\implies y(s)=c_0t^{a-1}+(\alpha-1)c_1t^{\alpha-2}\implies \boxed{y(t)=c_0t^{\alpha-1}+c_1 t^{\alpha-2}} $$

Please correct me and give me feedback!

Let’s try something else and simplify your definition:

Note that:

$$\frac d{dt}\int_0^t f(s,t,a)ds=\int_0^t \frac {df(s,t,a)}{dt}+f(t,t,a)$$

which I tried to use to simplify your fractional derivative definition, but it created a division by $0$ error.

Comment: This is nonsensical, specifically $\int\int\cdots dsds$.

Comment: Again with regard to your new edit, $\int_0^t\int_0^t\cdots dsds$ makes no sense whatsoever. You need to understand what integration means.